# how to fire FB event?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to fire this Facebook event but it does not work? Would like to implement some view tracking, maybe I have the wrong approach?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Facebook Like Button</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">


    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'xxxx', status: true, cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (href, widget) {
            alert('Facebook Like'); // I would like to call some tracking functionality here but does not fire:(
            console.log('like');
        });
    };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());


</script>
<fb:like></fb:like>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to fire it for the sake of unit testing? If so try: `FB.Event.fire('edge.create');`

Answer (score 0):

Or just place a like button?
For testing purposes this could point to a facebook page so you can actually unlike the page and try again...

Comment: You can unlike using the Like-Button. When you hover over it a small "x" does appear that allows you to unlike.